# INNER JOIN on multiple columns with multiple matches

Tags: oracle

How to find what rows got exact one match and what rows got more than one match in a INNER JOIN ?

```
SELECT A.Col1, B.Col2 FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.Col3 = B.Col3 AND A.Col4 = B.Col4;
```

As we know INNER JOIN returns rows with minimum one match, so to again reiterate my qustion, how to find which rows matched once and which rows got more than one match.

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and needed result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a window function to count how many records are coming from `B`:

```
SELECT A.Col1, B.Col2, Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.col3, b.col4) as bcount
FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.Col3 = B.Col3 AND A.Col4 = B.Col4;
```

Comment: Can this logic be expanded to more than two columns as well? I mean if I have 5 -6 join conditions.

Comment: It depends on what you consider a duplicate after the join, but as long as your partition includes whatever you count as unique then you should be good to go.

Comment: ok, like A.Col3 = B.Col3 AND A.Col4 = B.Col4 AND A.Col5 = B.Col5 AND A.Col6 = B.Col6;  This should give unique.

Comment: Oh. I see what you are asking. Yes, so if your ON looks like `A.Col3 = B.Col3 AND A.Col4 = B.Col4 AND A.Col5 = B.Col5 AND A.Col6 = B.Col6` then your `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY <list of fields>) as bcount`.. that `<list of fields>` should contain each one of those joined fields. That's essentially saying "Count each record in a group of records made up by these columns".

Comment: Thanks, with your support, I was able to implement what I wanted. I am posting a working example based on which I created the solution for everyone's info. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of JNevill's inputs, here is a working example of what I was looking for. I want to thank JNevill once again.

```
    create table A (col1 number, col3 number, col4 number, col5 number, col6 number);
    create table B (col2 number, col3 number, col4 number, col5 number, col6 number);

    insert into A values (1,2,3, 4, 5);
    insert into A values (2,3,4,5,6);
    insert into B values (3,4,5,6,7);
    insert into B values (4,2,3,4,5);
    insert into B values (5,2,3,8,9);
    insert into B values (6,3,4,5,6);
    insert into B values (7,3,4,5,6);

    SELECT Col1 FROM(
SELECT A.Col1,B.Col2, A.Col3, A.Col4, A.Col5 ,A.Col6, Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B.col3, B.col4, B.col5, B.col6) as bcount
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Col3 = B.Col3 AND A.Col4 = B.Col4 AND A.Col5 = B.Col5 AND A.Col6 = B.Col6) WHERE BCOUNT = 1;
```

So, I was looking for a column from table A which has exact one match for all the joining columns in table B.

Regards.